# Not able to scroll to div inside iframe from parent

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am able to trigger a click on accordion (implemented as div) from parent html using below jquery:

```
jQuery(iframe).contents().find('#XYZ').trigger( "click" );
```

Accordion is opening but my problem is that the opened accordion is hidden somewhere below and is not visible on screen.

Can someone suggest how to scroll to a div in iFrame from parent window? Both parent and child are in same domain. I tried `.scrollTo` and `.focus` but no positive result.

Comment: Are you using just jQuery or jQuery UI as well?

Comment: Both. jQuery and jQuery UI

Comment: >*"Accordian is opening but my problem is that the opened accordian is hidden somewhere below and is not visible on screen."* What do you click to open accordion? Is the accordion not at top of page inside iframe?

Comment: Existing page with property overflow-y:scroll has multiple iFrames and each iFrame contains accordions. Issue is the with the accordions that are not visible on the screen and we need to manually scroll to see the content.

Comment: There is also a top floating menu on the page and i am able to open respective accordion inside iframe on click of menu link by jQuery(iframe).contents().find('#XYZ').trigger( "click" ). But the opened accordion is not becoming visible after trigger and is still hidden with the scroll. I am looking for jQuery(iframe).contents().find('#XYZ').some jquery to avoid manual scroll and make the accordian/div visible

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting the hash in the iframe url

```
jQuery(iframe)[0].contentWindow.location.hash='XYZ';
```

Comment: Sorry. I am not sure how to use it to scroll to my accordian/div. I have also added above more details about my page. Thanks for your reply!

Comment: because url hash automatically scrolls to that id in page

Answer (score 0):

I can help you with a way to make an accordion adjust itself once it's opened, but I won't recreate your layout to test if it works.

1. Because iframes are hard to create a working example for.
2. Although I do recreate iframe environments that work, you haven't provided enough code to make it worth my while.
3. There's too many factors in your environment to consider anyhow.

What I offer **works under normal circumstances**, it's not tested under the environment you have described. Having said that, the following Snippet demonstrates how an accordion can automatically adjust it's position vertically after it's opened.

**Note:** If the accordion is at the very bottom of the page and the iframe at the very top, you may need to make more vertical space below the accordion to allow it to reach the iframe's view. A `<footer>` would be perfect.

#### SNIPPET

```css
footer {
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>CHILD</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/dark-hive/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <h1>TOP of CHILD PAGE</h1>
  </header>
  <hr/>
  <main>
    <section>
      <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows
        by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic
        life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli,
        but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown
        Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way.</p>

      <p>On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little Blind Text should turn around
        and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe and Parole and dragged her into their agency, where they abused
        her for their projects again and again. And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her. Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in
        Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into
        your mouth.</p>

      <p>Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her
        not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached
        the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then
        she continued her way. On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little
        Blind Text should turn around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe and Parole and dragged her into
        their agency, where they abused her for their projects again and again.</p>

      <p>And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her. Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the
        Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing
        has no control about the blind texts it is an almost unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there
        were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the
        Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then she continued her way.
        On her way she met a copy. The copy warned the Little Blind Text, that where it came from it would have been rewritten a thousand times and everything that was left from its origin would be the word "and" and the Little Blind Text should turn
        around and return to its own, safe country. But nothing the copy said could convince her and so it didn’t take long until a few insidious Copy Writers ambushed her, made her drunk with Longe and Parole and dragged her into their agency, where
        they abused her for their projects again and again. And if she hasn’t been rewritten, then they are still using her. Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated
        they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It</p>
    </section>
    <section>
      <div class="accordion">
        <h4>Accordion</h4>
        <div class="frame">
          <div class="content">
            <p>Far far away, behind the word mountains, far from the countries Vokalia and Consonantia, there live the blind texts. Separated they live in Bookmarksgrove right at the coast of the Semantics, a large language ocean. A small river named Duden
              flows by their place and supplies it with the necessary regelialia. It is a paradisematic country, in which roasted parts of sentences fly into your mouth. Even the all-powerful Pointing has no control about the blind texts it is an almost
              unorthographic life One day however a small line of blind text by the name of Lorem Ipsum decided to leave for the far World of Grammar. The Big Oxmox advised her not to do so, because there were thousands of bad Commas, wild Question Marks
              and devious Semikoli, but the Little Blind Text didn’t listen. She packed her seven versalia, put her initial into the belt and made herself on the way. When she reached the first hills of the Italic Mountains, she had a last view back on
              the skyline of her hometown Bookmarksgrove, the headline of Alphabet Village and the subline of her own road, the Line Lane. Pityful a rethoric question ran over her cheek, then</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>

  </main>
  <hr/>
  <footer>
    <h2>BOTTOM of CHILD PAGE</h2>
  </footer>
  <script src="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    $(function() {
      $(".accordion").accordion({
        heightStyle: 'content',
        collapsible: true,
        active: false,
        animate: 500
      });

      $('.accordion').on('click', function() {
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
          xOffset = $(self).offset();
          $('body,html').animate({
            scrollTop: xOffset.top
          });
        }, 700);
      });

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```